# Why is my jQuery Mobile include apparently not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I had a great working PhoneGap mobile web-app project, then my laptop died. I had all the files saved to the cloud, so no trouble with code loss, but now I've been trying to rebuild the project and that's where the trouble is.

I've set the whole thing up again, and it's loading alright, all the html elements are there as coded, but the jQuery Mobile css doesn't seem to be including on any of my pages, given that all I see is a white page with normal underlined blue links. Very unattractive.

Here's the beginning of my code on each page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css"/>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
```

Which should be alright, I would think...it worked before, anyway.

What's missing? I'm inclined to think it's somewhere in the configuration rather than the code, give the circumstances.

Should there be some sort of cordova.css file? Because there isn't one, and I thought there used to be. (About to Google that...)

Comment: have you check firebug to see if your resources are loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that code.jquery.com is in ExternalHosts in your phonegap.plist (or cordova.plist)?

Comment: That was it. Completely forgot about that from last time. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Please try whit this,

```
https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css
```

Hope this helps. :)